# A vector of strings(read from the keyboard)

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a phone book program and I want to improve it by putting my parameters 
in a vector of strings that are read from keyboard.

I try this code, but the parameters are not recognized in vector;

```
string firstname, lastname, country, city, street;
string phone;
vector<string> user( firstname, lastname, country, city, street, phone);
```

Comment: Note that there will be no connection between the variables and the vector's elements; modifying `user[0]` has no effect on `firstname` and vice versa. I suspect that what you really need is a `struct`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I have a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the initializer list constructor (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector #7) like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
  string firstname, lastname, country, city, street;
  string phone;
  vector<string> user{ firstname, lastname, country, city, street, phone };

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but i'm not familiarized with auto main(), I can use int main() instead ?

Comment: My program is with class, so I put that in class ?Or it's working in main ?

Comment: @Imre_talpa of course, I changed the original source code, the auto main was my bad

Comment: @Imre_talpa Yes, you could have this user information as a member of another class - but in this case you should include the relevant source code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Do you initialize your strings with a value before adding them to a vector? How do you read them? By the code, I assume you loop through a vector with std::cin getting values. If so - pass pointers to a vector instead of values.

```
/*vec declaration*/
std::string firstname, lastname, country, city, street, phone;
std::vector<std::string*> user{ &firstname, &lastname, &country, &city, &street, &phone};
...
/*reading*/
for(auto i : user)
    std::cin >> *i;
...
/*then you can access them from the desired string*/
std::cout << firstname; // will print firstname that you've read
```

SUGGESTION1: Use array / std::array if you know the size of the container. Vector should be used when you know your container will grow in size (adding / removing new elements).

SUGGESTION2: better would be to use a structure for a user - it will be easier to both manage and read your code later on, so f.ex:

```
struct User
{
    std::string firstname,
                lastname,
                country,
                city,
                street,
                phone;
}
```

And then use vector to store all of your users in one container. You could always use the secondary vector like you do now if it's easier for you to read it that way.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the root problem and the declaration is still illegal. Moreover, storing pointers is not a good suggestion in general anyway.

Comment: Oh true, didnt notice hes using round brackets. 
About the pointers - thats why I suggested using a struct.